# How I can add my JQuery script into single wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress

I want to add my JQuery script into single Wordpress page, but I dont know how. Example of script I'd like to inject:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(window).height() }, 600);

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

This code works fine when injected in plain HTML, but how can I do the same for Wordpress?

Comment: add these code in WordPress footer.php file

Comment: HI I also done it what you saying but its not working in wordpress 3.9

Comment: wp-content/themes/your-theme/footer.php file. right?

Comment: boopathi my friend I want this code have to work in single post page page name single.php and this code still i dont know where to add but i tried it in footer its not working

Comment: use jQuery instead of $ symbol

Comment: using `jQuery` instead `$`, typical `$` shortcut for jQuery doesn’t work.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(window).height($)}, 600);
  return false;
  
 });  
 this is code now and I made a new js file insert in theme js folder and made a function in functions.php

Comment: my function is 

function custom() {

 //wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 
 wp_register_script('add-custom-js' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js' , array('jquery'),'',true );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' . 'custom' );

Noe tell me how i insert this function in my single.php page thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a couple of options, the function you created above will add it to all pages (you were registering the script but not actually calling it, thats why its not working. see correction below).

If you want you can simply place the wp_enqueue_script() function below in your template (without add action and the custom() function

or directly write it into the template file (lots of arguments about whether this is acceptable coding practice, but it works)

or require_once / include_once the file in the correct sequence (you are using document.ready so you can do this anywhere below the header (if you already have jquery loaded in the header, if in the footer, must be below the footer) same rules apply for directly writing into the file.

```
 function custom() { 

 wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
 wp_enqueue_script('add-custom-js' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js' , array('jquery'),'',true ); 
 } 
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' . 'custom' );
```

- also WP uses non conflict jquery so you need to use jQuery instead of the the shorthand vers $. there are a few alternative ways to use the shorthand if you google it.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I feel the best way for adding a JavaScript to a particular page/post is to use [ShortCode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Add this:

```
function add_my_script() {
    return "<script>
                 //your jQuery here
            </script>";
}  
 add_shortcode( 'myCustomShortCode', 'add_my_script' );
```

to your `function.php` file. Your function.php file is location at `/wp-content/themes/<name of theme>/`

**NOTE: Use `'` instead of `"` in your `<script>` to continue inside the `return` statement.**

Now simply add the shortcode `[myCustomShortCode]` in your page.

Answer (score 0):

just edit a page in wordpress, select text view (not formatted text) and paste your script wherever you like.