# How to make a jquery plugin work with wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I've been trying to get this jquery-plugin to work on a wp-site on a single page: https://github.com/almightynay/jQuery-Sakura

But I'm clearly doing one or two things wrong. I came across the following two questions that I've been working with to try and get it to function, but still failing.

[How I can add my JQuery script into single wordpress page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969155/how-i-can-add-my-jquery-script-into-single-wordpress-page)

[How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

So. Here's what I've done so far.

1. I added this to the header.php

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
    href="wp-content/themes/themename/css/jquery-sakura.min.css" />`

2. I added this to the functions.php

   ```
   function add_my_script() {
   return '<script>
                //your jQuery here
                <script src="wp-content/themes/themename/js/jquery-sakura.min.js"></script>

   // domReady
   $(function() {
       $("body").sakura();
   });

   // windowLoad
   $(window).load(function() {
       $("body").sakura();
   });

           </script>';}  
   add_shortcode( 'sakuraattempt', 'add_my_script' );
   ```

This differs slightly from what one of the previous questions I found said because I ran into a syntax error for `$('body').sakura();` that didn't like the single quote ', I tried double which was accepted, but don't know if that's correct.

3. I added shortcode [sakuraattempt] to the page.
4. I uploaded the js and css files to wp-content/themes/themename/css/ (or js) and edited the filepaths in the two above code snippets in 1+2 to point to the same. The files were:

`jquery-sakura.css
jquery-sakura.js
jquery-sakura.min.css
jquery-sakura.min.js`

The only result I get on the page is this blob of text appearing:

`// domReady $(function() { $("body").sakura(); }); // windowLoad $(window).load(function() { $("body").sakura(); });`

I would like to understand where I went wrong with this so that I can get this correct in future. There's a lot of nice jquery out there that I'd like to be able to fully understand how to implement by myself.

Thanks for your time! I apologise if anything here is outside of typical Stackoverflow etiquette, this is my first post.

Comment: Did you import the code into your theme? Your css and style links are relative paths, but if you didn't grab the code from the github repo and add to your theme, it won't load. You may also need to enqueue the files after they're there.

Comment: I say don't, I've opted for make a plugin, and add it's script using wp_enque_script (I think that's what it is) so it gets added in like a normal js file.. because it is, also I recommend using `jQuery(document).ready(function($){})`

Comment: You could also add a `console.log('hello world')` to see if it's running

Comment: I apologise! That's a detail I definitely left out - Yes I also uploaded the js+css files to `wp-content/themename/css` (or js). I also edited those lines in the above examples in 1+2 to the same paths. I'm going to edit that into the above question now.

Comment: Why is there a script tag inside your script tag?

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ that's what I ended up with when following along with answers to other questions. 

I assume you're implying that shouldn't happen and is wrong, would you mind pointing out where/how it should be corrected? Hopefully I can work out why I misunderstood the other tutorials on this topic.

Comment: On @KevinB 's criticism I've altered the functions.php code to:

`function add_my_script() {
    return '<script src="wp-content/themes/Avada/js/jquery-sakura.min.js">` - removing the script inception he pointed out.

This now no longer outputs the codey blob on the page mentioned in the question, but still doesn't provide the effect.

Comment: You can't put code inside a script tag that has a src attribute.

Comment: Ok so if I'm understanding this correctly wa @KevinB is that there are 2 separate scripts there that should be used independently to make it work? The one with a src attribute and the one with the on window load function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect works now. Here's what I did to get there.

1. Added the js+css files to the server in `/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/css/` and `/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/js/`
2. Added to header.php

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/css/jquery-sakura.min.css" />`

(inside the  tags)

3. Added to functions.php

   ```
   function add_my_script() {
       return '<script src="/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/js/jquery-sakura.min.js"></script>';
   }  
    add_shortcode( 'sakuraattempt', 'add_my_script' );  

   function add_my_script2() {
   return '<script>

   // domReady
   jQuery(function() {
       jQuery("body").sakura();
   });

   // windowLoad
   jQuery(window).load(function() {
       jQuery("body").sakura();
   });

   jQuery("body").sakura("start", {
       blowAnimations: 
           "blow-soft-left",  // Horizontal movement animation names
       className: "sakura", // Class name to use
       fallSpeed: 1,        // Factor for petal fall speed
       maxSize: 14,         // Maximum petal size
       minSize: 4,          // Minimum petal size
       newOn: 200,          // Interval after which a new petal is added
       swayAnimations:     // Swaying animation names
           "sway-1",
   });

           </script>';
   }  
    add_shortcode( 'sakuraattempt2', 'add_my_script2' );
   ```
4. Added the shortcodes [sakuraattempt] and [sakuraattempt2] to the page I wanted the effect on.

Job done! There are probably better ways to go about this, but this is now functioning.

I additionally needed to add a z-index modifier to the `sakura` class so that the petals would always appear above all elements on the page.

If anyone has improvements/criticism to this approach my ears are open, otherwise I hope my hacky experience here helps someone else in future. Thanks partly to @kevinb for cryptically steering towards one of the problems I had.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding your javascript into a js file that is uploaded into your theme. Then you will want to enqueue your scripts in your functions file like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'sakura', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-sakura.min.js', 'jquery', false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', 'jquery', false, true );
```

The code here assumes that you have your javascript in a folder named 'js' and it is in your theme.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake and missed that part out of the things that I have done. My mistake! I actually have done that but left it out of the above. I've edited the original question to include that in part "4." now.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the function.php file of the currently active theme with the proper path of the js file that you want to add

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addScripts');

function addScripts()
{
   wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, false);

}